# How do I develop an understanding of how equations were created?

Tags: statistics, covariance, descriptive-statistics

*Firstly: having a lot of difficulty figuring out how to articulate this question due to lack of general math knowledge.  There are multiple questions posed below, but I feel like if I knew more they could be condensed into a single question and am hoping someone can suggest and edit to the effect of the below.  Thank you in advance for your consideration and assistance on this point!*

**Background**

I'm taking a course which includes descriptive statistics. In that course they describe the method of calculating covariance and provide that equation.  I find myself wondering - *why* did they choose to define it as they did (using multiplication instead of addition between the terms in the numerator - not even sure if that description is accurate).

**My question?**

Are equations for things like covariance derived from looking at phenomenon and 'cracking the code' of how those phenomenon could be described mathematically via a proof?  Or does one, at some level of mathematical skill, say: I want to model this phenomenon and I want that model to have these features and qualities to its output, therefore, I choose this particular structure to achieve that goal and then I prove that functionality through a proof?

If the latter case - what progression of mathematical learning develops that skillset?
Is the same skillset used in both cases?

**Why I ask**

If I understand the motivation of the creator of the covariance equation, I could compare it to my own motivation and perhaps come up with a different approach to the same problem that better fits my own goals because maybe our goals are similar but not the same...

Thank you again for any advice on how to simplify this..

Comment: Not sure if this counts as an answer so I will leave it as a comment. In my experience, in school you are given definitions and use them to solve problems, but in the realm of research, you solve a lot of problems, notice commonalities, and then create definitions. How equations and definitions come to be is hugely important in understanding them!

Comment: @IAAW - ty for the insight!  So are all definitions products of observations or are there examples where someone said: I want a tool to tell me these sorts of things, and then they designed math to create the intended effect?  When you say 'research' is that implying the process wherein new mathematical tools are built to solve various applications (i.e. create equations)?  I feel like we can refine my understanding in these comments and I can then rephrase the Q that you can then answer if that makes sense.. ty either way !

Comment: I'm going to talk about the research domain, since I feel that fits your question best. For most of the concepts in probability, including covariances, there are very strict and rigorous definitions. This definitions codify into mathematics our concepts of logic, and seem to agree with reality in almost all cases. Statisticians then look at specific problems and situations, think of a model that 'should' explain it, and try to come up with the mathematics and equations to describe how these rigorous definitions would apply to this specific model, and how would one make the model fit the data.