# Do observations of phenomenon drive the development of equations or does a conceptual need for a tool drive their development instead?

Tags: education, math-history

I'm attempting to develop an understanding of how equations are developed and wondered whether or not all equations started their development in the quest to document observable phenomenon or are there any 'purely synthetic' equations, which are developed from the basis of a thought in order to produce numeric results which are useful in some way.

Put another way:
Do observations of phenomenon drive the development of equations or does a conceptual need for a tool drive their development instead?

The reason I ask, is because as someone who is a novice in mathematics (arithmetic skill, elementary algebra and descriptive stats), the choice of the construction of equations / their form always leads me to wonder *why* this form was chosen.  In particular as I delve further into stats I have seen descriptions where certain equations may be adjusted based 'on ones need' which further deepens the difficulty of just using a tool blindly and wondering at what point or in what way I can develop the skill to discern how to choose how to alter an equation to better fit a desired outcome...

I attempted to articulate this originally [HERE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4795880/how-do-i-develop-an-understanding-of-how-equations-were-created), then asked about whether it made sense to start a new question [HERE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36032/should-i-leave-my-question-open?cb=1), but for lack of feedback in either, I decided to open this query and post any positive results as link backs to those two questions for the community's later use.  If there is a better way to approach asking this please let me know and I'll be happy to adjust accordingly.

Comment: Interesting question. From the linked post, it seems you're more interested in equations meant to model physical phonomena rather than pure mathematical phenomena, specifically those where there is some degree of freedom when defining relevant concepts. Is this your main interest in this post as well, or do you intend to consider more general equations from any domain in this post?

Comment: The part of math we need for science like physics is quite tiny. Most of the actual mathematics has nothing to do with the physical world.

Comment: @C-RAM - Not sure if its appropriate to ask what 'purely mathematical phenomena' are here but if it is I'd like to know more because perhaps I am and I just don't know it.  The root of my ask is derived from studying descriptive stats and I suppose I considered the observations we're analyzing as 'natural phenomenon' and the insights were attempting to derive 'synthetic' creations that serve a purpose.  Its very hard to know how to articulate my 'true question'.  Please ask me more clarifiers!  Tysm for your collective patience.

Comment: By equations that model pure mathematical phenomena, I mean equations like: the [binomial theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Statement), [Euler's formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula), the [residue theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem), the [Liebniz formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_determinants), etc. I mean formulas that express things about mathematical objects, and are not explicitly created to model things in the real world (even if they are sometimes/often useful for modeling the real world).

Comment: Pure mathematics tends to deal mostly with these sorts of formulas/equations rather than the alternative(s), and I'd guess most people here probably think of these "pure math" equations when they hear the word "equation". I suppose you can allow others to interpret the question as they will, and then write a new one more or less focussed on stats (perhaps giving examples of equations you're interested in) if you don't get the sorts of answer's you're looking for.  Keep in mind there is also https://stats.stackexchange.com/ which might be more appropriate depending on what you want to ask.

Comment: @C-RAM - Ok, ty for the context!  I guess I've always thought of numbers as natural phenomenon.  When I say 'synthetic' in this case, I meant 'originated in human thought' as opposed to 'originated through observation of nature'.  Does that context make my question more clear or perhaps answerable?  I'm thinking perhaps the real question I'm asking is "Do observations of phenomenon drive development (of equations) or does a conceptual need for a tool drive development." And development I guess I'm using as 'production'/originating.  If none of that makes sense I may just have to learn more!

Comment: Fair... I think the statement "Do observations of phenomenon drive development (of equations) or does a conceptual need for a tool drive development." does a good job of explaining what you're looking for.

Comment: @C-RAM - Ok!  That's exciting!  I've updated the title and body to reflect our discussion - lets see if this improves answerability!  Thank you in either case for your time and thought, it's been extremely helpful for me.

Comment: It's an interesting question but the answer might be field dependent. Say, for example, different in physics compared to say macro-economics.

Comment: @markleeds - Ahhh, and that's starting to make sense to me, especially with C-RAM's earlier mention of 'pure mathematics' (of which I only have an inkling of what the really means).  I think this gives me a way to break this question down further - one about what 'pure math' means, and another two posing this question in the context of 'in pure math' and 'in non-pure-math' scenarios.  Perhaps your comment is the right answer to this question and when I pose the others, they can be referred to in this question.  Thoughts?

Comment: A L. I can't really add much. I just threw that in because I mostly work in econometrics  ( but my background is statistics and hobby is teaching myself math ) so I've noticed that.  If you read about say brownian motion in sde some books, it can be derived from some "physicalities. I forget the book that did it best but I'll try to find it. It was a stochastic differential equations text that made me realize that. maybe arnold ? thanks for interesting question. I'll just eavesdrop going forward.

Comment: @markleeds - No problem at all!  Ty again for your insight!

Comment: your question was definitely thought provoking but, like I said, I think it varies from field to field. The stochastic differential equations book is by Schuss. You may find the physical way he derives relations interesting.

Comment: @markleeds - purchased ty for everything!!

Answer (score 2):

Since I can't comment I will summarise my thoughts in this answer. In my experience, and from historical literature that I've read, the answer is "yes" to both of your questions. To clarify: As far as I'm concerned, it starts with the need or want to describe a particular physical phenomena. To this end, we first agree on relevant definitions and then observe the phenomena in order to formulate a "theorem" (e.g an equation). Sometimes it is easy to derive the equation, other times it requires much more technicalities, including mathematical tricks and tools. Whenever that is the case, it means the problem moves to a more theoretical setting, also increasing the risk of a less intuitive final result. But this is where the motivation for research on pure mathematics lies, answering questions such as: can we develop a theory which improves the equation in terms of computational complexity, intuitiveness, simplicity etc? This research does not (necessarily) have any particular practical importance but rather focuses on the theoretical parts of an equation/model, and has in turn introduced pure mathematics as an independent field of study.

You also ask how to decipher when to adjust an equation based on your needs. The short answer is simply to read proofs and practice on problem solving. Make sure you have seen all relevant equations and definitions for your course and how they depend on one another - there is always a reason for an adjustment to an equation and you should be able to find it from there. Once you have seen enough you will get a feel for it.

:)

Comment: Tysm for signing up just to answer this!  Leaving open through end of week then this will receive the answer designation unless something more compelling comes along.